# Can we remove unsubscribe button from Pardot emails?

Tags: pardot

I want to completely remove the unsub from my email template on Pardot. Because the emails i am sending are internal for my company.

Kindly help if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to customize the unsubscribe button on Pardot emails.  Meaning that the functionality for that button is going to remain consistent across all Pardot emails.

For more details over what lists prospects can opt, you can check on [Email Preference Center](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_emails_preference_center_parent.htm&type=5) within Pardot.